# What does | mean when diff is run on two files?

Tags: diff

When I run:

```
diff -y <file1> <file2>
```

what is the `|` character telling me?

i.e.

```
Video_Codec_List : v210  |  Codecs Video : v210
```

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the GNU `diffutils` documentation (using `info diffutils "output formats" "side by side"`)

```
`|'
     The corresponding lines differ, and they are either both complete
     or both incomplete.
```

FYI the complete list of markers is given as

```
white space
     The corresponding lines are in common.  That is, either the lines
     are identical, or the difference is ignored because of one of the
     `--ignore' options (*note White Space::).

`|'
     The corresponding lines differ, and they are either both complete
     or both incomplete.

`<'
     The files differ and only the first file contains the line.

`>'
     The files differ and only the second file contains the line.

`('
     Only the first file contains the line, but the difference is
     ignored.

`)'
     Only the second file contains the line, but the difference is
     ignored.

`\'
     The corresponding lines differ, and only the first line is
     incomplete.

`/'
     The corresponding lines differ, and only the second line is
     incomplete.
```

Comment: Thanks. I do seem to be getting lines that are identical but still have the | 'Title                                    : 001        | Title                            : 001'

Comment: Hard to diagnose unless you can post a minimal example of your input files: my *guess* would be the files have different line endings (LF vs CR-LF)