# When does diff use | in a side by side diff?

Tags: diff

in the documentation to diff is said under "Showing Differences Side by Side":

```
‘|’
The corresponding lines differ, and they are either both complete or both incomplete.
```

What does *complete* and *incomplete* exactly mean? See also the example in [What does | mean when diff is run on two files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748738/what-does-mean-when-diff-is-run-on-two-files). Exists flavours of diff which interpret '|' differently?

Thanks Sigbert

Comment: Same question was asked two years ago an remains unanswered: [Diff side by side output with “|” (incomplete) sign](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105189/diff-side-by-side-output-with-incomplete-sign)

Answer (score 2):

This is the best description of ["incomplete line"](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/comparing_and_merging_linux_files/diff_042.html) I could find:

> When the last line of a file ends with a new line character it is a "complete line". Otherwise it is an "incomplete line".

For example, suppose F and G are one-byte files that contain just f and g, respectively. Then `diff F G` outputs:

```
1c1
< f
\ No newline at end of file
---
> g
\ No newline at end of file
```